# Download photos and videos from iPhone

Tags: mac, iphone, ios

Is there a way to download all my photos/videos from iPhone to a Mac without going through the Photos app?

I want to transfer all the files in a directory, but it seems really hard to do.

Comment: I use iTunes (you can use the MAC Photo App) and it works great. Reasonably easy to use as well.

Comment: @John - iTunes doesn't import, it only syncs from the Photos app. Photos was precisely what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: You can upload to iTunes and download from iTune to another device. . That is what I was referring to.

Comment: iTunes does not handle anything except sync from the Mac to iDevices. OP wants to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Image Capture, in Applications/Utilities.

From within Image Capture, you can also set each device to what app to automatically open [or not] when connected & also the default folder to store transferred images.

Test image showing connected iPhone with a single photo, plus a Camera SD card & connected printer/scanner. The Utility can acquire images from many types of device. It is the actual working 'engine' behind the Photos App.

Note: This only works from the Camera Roll. Previously saved/shared images you would have to acquire from their original storage.

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason for not using the Photos app it is still the easiest way to transfer photos. I am a professional photographer and use this method. To copy selected photos from my iPhone to my Mac I import them using the Photos app and then immediately select and Export the images to a folder using the option "Export Unmodified Originals"

If you want you can then delete them from the Photos app.

Comment: I apologize for seeming abrasive, but this is terrible advice for anybody who has a large sum of photos that almost definitely could have errors. Additionally, this adds no customizability and is an utterly terrible solution. I've outlined a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1727943/what-to-do-when-importing-photos-and-videos-from-iphone-through-photos-and-windo/1727944#1727944).

Comment: Well I am not on Windows and have never had problems like you describe. The Photos app in MacOS just does a simple copy to the desktop machine and leaves the originals on the iPhone. I haven't had problems, even with thousands of photos at a time.