# What to do when importing photos and videos from iPhone through Photos and Windows Explorer fails due to unexpected errors

Tags: windows, iphone, photos

This is a problem I've had across several phones, several desktops, and is a problem that nobody seems to have an answer for, leaving several GB of data unaccounted for and stuck in phones. What the entire internet recommends as a solution is using Photos, but due to the sheer incompetence or negligence of the developers of this simplified software, it barely allows any customization or failsafe. If one photo fails to download, the entire program will crash with probably one of the most useless error messages aside from the Windows 8+ bluescreens.

[image]

This leads to a second option that I've found, which only some blogs recommend save for downloading some Ultra Special Photo Manager™ as an advertisement as the "blog post" is hosted on the website of that commercial photo manager ([like this, for instance!](https://www.copytrans.net/blog/6-ways-to-transfer-your-iphone-photos-to-pc-without-itunes/)). The option is to use Windows Explorer, which (obviously) allows for more customization as it is a more fleshed out interface, allowing for searching, filtering for videos (something Photos can't even start to do), and many others. There still is an issue with this problem, though, and that is that for some godforsaken reason, it falls back to an ancient dialog that as far as I can remember, dates back to Vista.

[image]

This has the exact same problems with the Photos app (albeit with some added customizability), as if one of these files fails, say with the following error (somehow even more verbose and infuriating than the Photos error), the entire move process will fatally fail.

[image]

This failure is very helpfully accompanied by not marking your progress by deleting the files from the source directory (as a move should do). This will most likely leave you in where I was a couple hours ago, copying the same files over and over again to ensure no half-imports.

What is the solution to this absolute mess of terrible software design and cursed methodology to do one of the simplest tasks that is copying files from your phone to your desktop?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the major problem that is the fatal failure in both of these solutions, the solution does actually employ the use of Explorer. Rather than just moving the files and folders over, leading to the Vista-era move dialog, simply adding a wildcard search criteria into the search bar (like IMG in this example) will actually allow you to use the modern Windows 8+ dialog.

[image]

I have no idea why this works, as there shouldn't be any reason to intentionally use an outdated dialog conditionally based on a source folder. I can only imagine that it's an capitalistic attempt from Microsoft's part to dissuade using iPhones, but I might just be a conspiracy theorist.

[image]

Either way, using this method, the first erroring file it sees should hopefully *gracefully* error, giving a saving grace of a helpful dialog:

[image]

This will allow you to simply check the box and skip all of the erroring files without preventing the entire debacle.

Hope this helps, I've been tearing my hair out at this and seemingly nobody on this green earth has had any solution to this, simply just blaming you for getting your files corrupted even though this problem has come up time and time again.

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to go to the iPhone's settings -> Photos -> Scroll to the bottom -> Transfer to MAC or PC -> Keep Originals -> Reconnect iPhone to the PC. Otherwise, iPhone will try to convert `.heic` images to `.jpg` and `hvec` encoded `.mov` files to `h264`. This will result in some files returning error if you try to copy them.